# Drop down list - hide when another item is clicked

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I am using the codedrops custom drop-down lists to create a drop down menu
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/10/04/custom-drop-down-list-styling/

However I can't get it one menu item to close if I click on another menu item, also because I have a second nested list that is toggling in the main list I can' hide the dropdown when I click on the active link.

I need the dropdown to close if I click on either a second nav item, outside the menu or if I click on the nav link for a second time (but now when I click on the second dropdown link)

```
        function DropDown(el) {
            this.dd = el;
            this.initEvents();
        }
        DropDown.prototype = {
            initEvents : function() {
                var obj = this;

                obj.dd.on('click', function(event){
                    $(this).addClass('active');
                    event.stopPropagation();
                }); 
            }
        }

        $(function() {

            var dd = new DropDown( $('.ddMenu') );

            $(document).click(function() {
                $('.ddMenu').removeClass('active');
            });

        });


        $(function () {
        var $subs = $('li.expanded > ul').hide();

        $('li.expanded > a').click(function (e) {
            var $ub = $(this).next().stop(true, true).slideToggle(300, function(){
                $('li.expanded > a').addClass('close').removeClass('open');
                if($ub.is(':visible')){
                   $(this).prev('a').addClass('open').removeClass('close');
                }
            });

            $subs.not($ub).slideUp();
            e.preventDefault();
        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u48Pn/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your DropDown prototype to this ([JSFiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/hC7aD/1/)):

```
DropDown.prototype = {
                initEvents : function() {
                    var obj = this;

                    obj.dd.on('click', function(event){
                        if(!$(event.target).hasClass('secondDropDown'))
                        {
                           if($(this).hasClass('active'))
                               $(this).removeClass('active');
                           else
                               $(this).addClass('active');
                           event.stopPropagation();
                        }
                    }); 
                }
            }
```

**CODE UPDATED:** [JSFiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/hC7aD/4/)

Comment: that doesn't close the first dropdown when you click on the second, also it also closes the dropdown when you click on the second internal dropdown

Comment: true. I'm trying to fix that